# Make the drop-down menu's width dynamic

Tags: html, css

[My website](http://djdavid98.zymichost.com/.math/) uses a drop-down menu for the things you can do on the page.

HTML:

```
<table class="navbar">
    <td class="menuNormal geometry" width="135px" onmouseover="menu('exp',this);" onmouseout="menu('col',this);">
        <p class="tdesc">
            <span lang="hu">Geometria</span>
            <span lang="en">Geometry</span>
        </p>
        <div class="menuNormal dropdown" width="inherit">
            <table class="menu" width="inherit">
                <tr><td class="menuNormal">
                    <a href="javascript:geodesc('squa')" class="menuitem">
                        <span lang="hu">Négyzet</span>
                        <span lang="en">Square</span>
                    </a>
                </td></tr>
                ...
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

table.navbar {
background-color: ButtonFace;
font: menu;
}

p.tdesc {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
text-align:center;
font: menu;
}

table.menu{
font-size: 8pt;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

td.menuNormal{
padding: 0px;
color: ButtonText;
vertical-align: top;
}

td.menuHover{
padding: 0px;
color: HighlightText;
vertical-align: top;
background-color: Highlight;
}

div.menuNormal{
display: none;
position: static;
}

div.menuHover{
border: 1.5px solid ButtonShadow;
background-color: Menu;
display: inline;
position: absolute;
}

a.menuitem:link{
text-decoration: none;
color: ButtonText;
padding: 2.5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid GrayText;
display: block;
}

a.menuitem:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: HighlightText;
padding: 2.5px;
background-color: Highlight;
border-bottom: 1px solid GrayText;
display: block;
}

.hover {
border:3px ridge #8CA3FF;
background-color: #C9D4FF;
font-style:normal;
}
```

Currently, this solution is not the perfect one, since the menu's width is fixed, and when I tried to make it look like a bit more drop-down-ish, it extended the width of the top label when showing the actual options.

I need a method that I could use to make the options appear like an actual drop-down would, and make the label width fit the text that it contains.

Comment: Please don't ask people to reverse-engineer external pages. Add a simple working example to your question.

Comment: tables should be used for displaying *tabular data*, you should use a `UL>LI>A` combo for this. *side comment*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is something new you are putting together and you have complete control over it and the goal is to make a nice website (not about showing an understanding of CSS) and you have no limitations such as **not** using an existing library, then I would suggest trying out [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) and using a fluid container and navigation as a base and then add your own CSS on top for specific design changes if required.

Comment: I've heard about bootstrap before, it's just that I didn't know it can do this as well. Thanks!